# Output average or top values cpu and mem usage of running script in log file

Tags: linux, bash

my goal is to have image optimization script that will run every day (with cron). After script is tone, it will write log file.

It will be nice that i have top values of cpu and mem of that script, or maybe even average usage. How to achive that?

UPDATE:

my script

`function log_me {
    echo
    echo -e $greentext"===========  Optimiziation $d  =========="$normal
    echo "Time: $h"
    output_msg
    echo ""
    error_section
    echo ""
    mod_img_section
    echo "Script finished in '$m_runtime' and $s_runtime. Or $m_runtime:$s_runtime"
    echo "-------------------------------------------------------------"
}`

https://pastebin.com/n8u2xwT9

Comment: show your current efforts

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i edit post. Script is still in progress. I didnt do anything for that CPU and mem usage bc i still dont know how to do that part.